# Scanf an unknown amount of integers ,and stop the procedure while get an '\n'

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{

    int a[100];
    char mi[200];
    char delims[] = "\040";
    char * li;

    fgets(mi,200,stdin);
    li = mi;
    li = strtok(li,delims);
    a[0] = atoi(li);
    for(int i=1;li!=NULL;i++)
    {
        li = strtok(NULL,delims);
        a[i] = atoi(li);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

all the input were separate by space.
I wrote one,but it's so complex,so I wonder if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty much how it needs to be done, although you have a small problem with your tokenizing loop: think about what will happen when there are no more tokens remaining. I would recommend using more meaningful variable names, to make code more self-documenting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    int values[100];
    char linebuf[200];
    char *token;

    fgets(linebuf,sizeof(linebuf),stdin);
    token = strtok(linebuf,' ');
    for(int i = 0; token; i++) {
        values[i] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL,' ');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If it were my code, I might prefer to use `strtol` instead of `atoi`, to be able to have some more error checking to screen out extraneous (non-numerical) characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead of `atoi`, you don't need to use `strtok`. The function `strtol` will automatically discard all leading [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) characters and will tell you the first character that it didn't convert, so you know where to continue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUMBERS 100

int main(void)
{
    long numbers[MAX_NUMBERS];
    char line[200];
    char *p;

    fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin );
    p = line;

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++ )
    {
        long ret;
        char *q;

        numbers[i] = strtol( p, &q, 10 );
        if ( p == q )
            break;

        p = q;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you do proper error checking, and print the result, the code will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_NUMBERS 100

int main(void)
{
    long numbers[MAX_NUMBERS];
    int num_converted;
    char line[200];
    char *p;
    int i;

    //attempt to read one line of input
    if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "error reading line!" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //make sure that entire line was read
    if ( strchr( line, '\n' ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input line was too long!" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //begin at the start of the line
    p = line;

    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++ )
    {
        long ret;
        char *q;

        //attempt to convert one number
        errno = 0;
        numbers[i] = strtol( p, &q, 10 );

        //break loop if it was unable to convert another number
        if ( p == q )
            break;

        //verify that the found number is not out of range
        if ( errno == ERANGE )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "number out of range!" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //continue after the converted number
        p = q;
    }

    //remember how many numbers were converted
    num_converted = i;

    //print how many numbers were converted
    printf( "Converted %d numbers:\n", i );

    //print all the converted numbers
    for ( i = 0; i < num_converted; i++ )
        printf( "%ld\n", numbers[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

If you run this code with the input `761 87 2387`, followed by a newline character, then the output will be the following:

```
Converted 3 numbers:
761
87
2387
```